# Get the class name of a TypeElement inside and annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, javac, processor

I'm writing an annotation processor that runs within javac.
It scans annotated classes and produces a resource file that contains class names.
These names will by used at runtime to be able to get the `Class<?>` thanks to `Class.forName(String)`.

How to get the class name (e.g. pgk1.pkg2.Foo$Bar) from a `javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement`.

**Tips:** I need neither the simple name (e.g. Bar), nor the qualified name (e.g. pgk1.pkg2.Foo.Bar).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The annotation processor is initialized by the compiler and receives a `ProcessingEnvironment` instance.

The method `Name ProcessingEnvironment.getElementUtils().getBinaryName(TypeElement)` returns a binary name that can be used to instanciate the class later on.